# Reading a particular data from a json

Tags: c#, arrays, json

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"user.FirstName":["The FirstName field is required."]}}
```

How to read the error message from here.eg The FirstName field is Required in c#.

Comment: How are you getting this JSON? Where you are trying to read this JSON? Client side or server side? What code have you tried for this? What error you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Create specific class to deserialize your Json Structure.

But there is a problem here.

> If you want to deserialize using class structure then you need to
>   change the property for "user.FirstName" to "user_FirstName" inside
>   your json structure, because inside c# variable/property you cannot
>   define "."

I have change that property "user.FirstName" to "user_FirstName" in your json and defined the classes

```
public class ModelState
{
    public IList<string> user_FirstName{ get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ModelState ModelState { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize using the below code

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonstring = @"{ ""Message"":""The request is invalid."",""ModelState"":{ ""user_FirstName"":[""The FirstName field is required.""] }}";
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<Example>(jsonstring);
        Console.WriteLine("Error Message : " + jsonObject.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Error Message : " + jsonObject.ModelState.user_FirstName);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Add `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` to the list of your namespaces and for that you should have references to "`System.Web.Extensions`"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class for deserializing response message:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> ModelState { get; set; }
}
```

And then use some library like [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm):

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);    
string[] errors = response.ModelState["user.FirstName"];
```

Or safer way - check the response message and property name before reading errors:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);
if (response.Message == "The request is invalid.")
{
    string[] errors;
    if (response.ModelState.TryGetValue("user.FirstName", out errors))
    {
        // use errors here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its work for me..

Answer (score 0):

First parse the JSON string to an object `var validation = JSON.parse(message)`
Then you can access the Message and the ModelState `validation.Message` etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {

            string myparameters = "&Address=" + m.Address + "&Address2=" + m.Address2 + "&ContactNumber=" + m.ContactNumber + "&ContactPerson=" + m.ContactPerson + "&Designation=" + m.Designation + "&EmailId=" + m.EmailId + "&Pincode=" + m.Pincode;
            client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string htmlresult = client.UploadString(posturl, "POST", myparameters);
            Console.WriteLine(htmlresult);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                Console.WriteLine("\nError code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var readerr = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    string text = readerr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }
```